# PHP MySQL Query Search with Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, crud

I have 2 tables in my databases, `tb_device` and `tb_label` which contain this for example:

```
tb_device
id (AI)  |   type  |  label  |  etc
-------------------------------------
  1      |   A123  |    1    |  test
  2      |   A561  |    3    |  test2
  3      |   A777  |    2    |  test3
  4      |   A222  |    3    |  test4

tb_label
id (AI)  |  label
-------------------
  1      |  Samsung
  2      |  Apple
  3      |  Dell
```

And I already create CRUD form (PHP) which display `tb_devices`. And this CRUD has a searching form on each columns. Other columns are working for search, but label columns isn't working because it's contain `id` from `tb_label`. I want to search label with label name like `samsung`, `apple`, `dell`, not with number. My code for searching:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
            FROM tb_device a, tb_label b
            WHERE
                type LIKE '%".@$_POST['type']."%' AND
                (a.label=b.id AND b.label LIKE '%".@$_POST['label']."%') AND
                etc LIKE '%".@$_POST['etc']."%'
            ORDER BY type
    ";
```

I try to input `dell`, but the result:

```
      3      |   A777  |    2    |  test3
```

Explanation : `dell` have `id` number `3`, and the result showing `id` number `3` from `tb_device`. Is there any solution to show the correct result?

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed  b.label in your query

```
 $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.label
                FROM tb_device a, tb_label b
                WHERE
                    a.type LIKE '%".@$_POST['type']."%' AND
                    (a.label=b.id AND b.label LIKE '%".@$_POST['label']."%') AND
                    etc LIKE '%".@$_POST['etc']."%'
                ORDER BY a.type
        ";
```

Comment: Ah I get it. Thanks for the answer, sir. That's work :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should only have the WHERE for tb_label.label = (your user input variable: Dell)

I believe you want to do a

```
INNER JOIN tb_label
ON tb_device.label = tb_label.id
```